# How can i change the Android Status Bar Color when using Vuetify PWA Template

Tags: android, vue.js, background-color, statusbar, vuetify.js

I am using the predefined PWA Template from VuetifyJS and i want to change/set the Android Status Bar BackgroundColor that will be used when the PWA is installed on my Android Phone.

Answer (score 3):

Add this somewhere in your head element with the colour of your choice as the content:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

[More info if you need it.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android)